# read text files

Tags: r

I wonder if this code reads a set of text files and resaves them with the same name. When I tested it, I found that the list generated in the reading phase is empty. This is my code:

```
library('textreadr')
path <- ("C:/testnum/")
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.txt") 
lines<-list()

for (i in 1:length(files)){
    lines[[i]] <- scan(files[i])
  }

lines[i]<-lapply(names(files), function(x) 
  writeLines(lines[x], file=paste(path, x, ".txt", sep = "")))
```

Comment: what makes you think `files` has names? Shouldn't it just be `lapply(files, ...)`?

Comment: Also, you will likely need to add `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)` since you're dealing with a different path (and that will change your code for `writeLines`).

Comment: You completely missed my points. `list.files` returns an unnamed `character` vector, so `names(files)` is `NULL`; but okay, you are more concerned with why it is not reading the files. Have you looked at `files`? It is a list of file names, *assuming that they are in the current directory*. Try `file.exists(files[1])` and see, it will likely be false. Now add `full.names=TRUE` to `list.files` and try it again. Additionally, your use of `lines[i]<-lapply(...)` ... where do you meaningfully define `i`? Its last use is as the last value of the `for` loop, which seems rather meaningless here.

Answer (score 2):

Several things to correct:

- `list.files` returns an unnamed `character` vector, so `names(files)` will be `NULL`
- `list.files` is currently returning *just file names*, not the full path to read them, so your `scan` calls will only work if your working directory has files with the same names; it is much better to be defensive and incorporate the full path into the filenames
- your use of `lapply(files, function(i) writeLines(files[i], ...))` is missing the point that `i` is each filename, not an index into the vector
- `scan` does its own open/close if you give it a filename, so we can simplify the code there
- `writeLines` returns `NULL`, not sure why you'd want to capture that into `lines[i]` (if `i` had a meaningful value even)
- None of the code you're using needs any of the packages you're loading. Not certain if you assume you need them for this functionality, or if you are using them elsewhere (in which case they should not be in the question).

Try this:

```
path <- ("C:/Users/abidi/Desktop/testingSet/testnum/")
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.txt", full.names=TRUE) 
lines <- sapply(files, scan, simplify=FALSE)
```

Then write them out while ignoring/discarding the output:

```
ign <- lapply(files, function(fn) writeLines(fn, paste0(fn, ".txt")))
```

That last line can be even shorter

```
ign <- Map(writeLines, lines, paste0(files, ".txt"))
```

In both cases, `ign` is merely a throw-away variable: the return value from `writeLines` is `NULL`, so all you'll have there is a vector or list of `NULL`s.

Lastly, I'm assuming you are doing something meaningful to the contents of `lines` between reading them in and re-writing them to new files (that have an *additional* `.txt` appended, e.g., `filename.txt.txt`).

Comment: Right, `writeLines` takes `con=`, not `file=`. I blindly copied from your code, sorry about that. See my edit.

Comment: That suggests either (1) your `lines` is created wrong, or (2) your `Map(...)` command is using `files` twice instead of `lines` first. It works for me, please check you copied the code correctly.