# Creating a loop for creating multiple sheet from multiple excel files in R

Tags: r, openxlsx

I have multiple excel files with data. I wanted to split the data in each excel file into multiple sheets within that particular excel file. I have already managed to do that with the following code:

```
library(Openxlsx)

data<- read.xlsx(file.choose())

splitdata <- split(data, data$Assigned)
splitdata 

workbook <- createWorkbook()

Map(function(data,name){

  addWorksheet(workbook, name)

  writeDataTable(workbook, name, data)

},splitdata, names(splitdata))

saveWorkbook(workbook, file = "WorkbookWithMultipleSheets.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

However, I have more than 50 excel files, for which I need to create multiple sheets using the code above. Is there any way to create a loop so that I won't have to write this data for each excel file that I have?

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You're halfway there (cognitively) by using `Map`. Why not turn this into a `function` and wrap it similarly in `lapply` or another `Map` (depending on your needs)? Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51274210/3358272